# Is that the correct question? (what film was?)

Tags: grammar, questions

> What film was?

And the answer is

> The film was very interesting.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What film was?

is simply not grammatical. It is wrong. The two most similar but valid questions I can think of are:

> What film was that?

(asks for the name of the film)

or

> What was the film  like?

(asks for a description or evaluation of the film). This could be answered by "The film was very interesting."

Answer (score 2):

If you want the answer to be  "The film was very interesting."
the correct question would be.

> How was the film?

Or

> Did you like the film?
>
> What do you think of the film?
>
> Was the film interesting?